# Populate fields (add new) in django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

How I can add same thing with add new fields in django (admin)?:
https://gyazo.com/e31dc35495f61032c9605acc3723946b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating objects from `python manage.py shell`

1) Create each instance of the model - football club in your case - from a list, data frame or whatever and store them in a list:

```
from django_app.models import ClubToChoose
# read the data from .csv or .txt file, etc. instead of this list
clubs = ['Flamengo', 'foo', 'bar']
# this list will contain your data in django format - as a model instance
clubs_model_instances = []

for club in clubs:
    model_instance = ClubToChoose(choice_text=club,
                                  votes=0)
    clubs_model_instances.append(model_instance)
```

2) Use `bulk_create()` method to add your choices to database:

```
ClubToChoose.objects.bulk_create(clubs_model_instances)
```

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create

This method works much faster than creating instances one-by-one, as described in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#create